# What export settings should I use in Premiere Pro for iBooks Author videos?

Tags: video, premiere, file-formats

I've tried using Adobe Premiere to save a video for iBooks Author. The problem is that when I export my project as a mpeg2 file the quality of the video degrades a lot.

I am using images to re-create a Ken Burns/panning and scaling effect. I want the quality of the exported video of the images I am using to remain as high as possible. I am aware that iBooks Author optimizes and resizes the imported videos automatically. But right now the quality of the video isn't up to the standard I would like it to be, even before the iBooks optimisation. 
What settings should I use in Premiere Pro to export a video that is going to be used in iBooks Author?

Frame rate 23.972

field order- progressive

Aspect- square pixel(1)

TV standard - NTSC

Level- 4.0

Bitrate encoding- VBR 2 pass

Target bitrate- 5 Mbps

Maximum Bitrate- 8Mbps

Keyframe distance- 72

Comment: From the [Apple support page on iBooks Author](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5065): "For video, you should use files with an .mp4 file extension."
So mpeg2 is not the way to go. Also the quality depends strongly on your source footage. Could you add to your question what sort of footage you're working with (size, format).

Comment: Yes im using an image that has a huge pixel count 7000x5000 or so... The image degrades greatly when turned into a mp4. i guess that's because the actual video is only 1920x1050 but if there's anyway to keep the quality of the original image I'd want to do that as at the moment i'm not sure if they're worth using.

Comment: Could you post the exact settings (bitrate, framesize, fps, etc...) that you use when you export your footage? Just update your question to include that information.